# what font within Android is closest to this image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, fonts, android-fonts

I have seen the below font used within several android applications, including **[Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en_GB)** etc. What free font is closest to this image and how can I make use of it within Android? Thanks

The closest (most similar) font I could find was: Roboto

[image]

Comment: The percentage numbers and gibabytes numbers aren't from the dame font. One has rounded corner, the other hasn't. (7 can be easily compared)

Comment: In addition to the answer already provided, note that the font's white color has a slight gradient. To prove that the effect is not an optical illusion, compare the two identical circles of the percent sign, or compare the text with the bigger font from the text with the smaller font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dnt know what 'Clean Master' app you have there cause on play store there are tons of apps named so .Maybe you give me exact package name .And I can tell you what font they use.

Any way the idea is you to download the apk file from play store and open it with winrar or something and look into the assets folder , cause there ppls put the fonts most of  the times and then they load fonts in app.

You can use this link to download apk's from google play.
http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

I just downlaoded this and I see in apk's asset folder 6 font files. You can download yourself and see it

***UPDATE**
They use this fonts in the apk :  Spoon Number , Icomoon and Miso Unit .
you can download them from the link i give you

Comment: That would be awesome :-) thanks. There is a link in my question, click the word Clean Master

Comment: I updated response you can download and get the fonts .Just uncompress the apk and go in assets/fonts   folder .You can use winzip or Winrar

Answer (score 1):

The font on the right of the image is likely to be Roboto but the large numbers are not. Have you tried using an identification tool such as: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ which allows you to upload an image. Failing that you could chance your luck emailing the developer of the app where you have seen it used.

Comment: plus 1 for that WTF tool